# Get value of Bootstrap DateTimePicker

Tags: javascript, null, undefined, datetimepicker

I know there are other questions like mine, but whatever I do it returns `null` or `undefined`. I don't know where I'm going wrong.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-6" style="height:130px;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker10'>
            <input type='text'></input>
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Check" onclick="dateCheck()" />
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var dates = {};

$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker10').datetimepicker({
        viewMode: 'years',
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    });
    //dates.strt = $('#datetimepicker10').datetimepicker().getDate();   //returns UNDEFINED
    //dates.strt = $('#datetimepicker10').find('input').val();          // doesn't display anything
    dates.diffInDays = (new Date($('#datetimepicker10').val()).valueOf()-new Date('2017-04-26').valueOf())/(3600*24*1000);
    dates.str = $('#datetimepicker10').data("DateTimePicker").date();
});

function dateCheck () {
    alert(dates.str);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check below code. hope it will help you !

```
<div class="col-sm-6" style="height:130px;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' >
                <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker10'></input>
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Check" onclick="dateCheck()" />
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dates = {};
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#datetimepicker10').datepicker({
         viewMode: 'years',
         format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
      });
   });

  function dateCheck() {
     dates.diffInDays = (new Date($('#datetimepicker10').val()).valueOf() - new Date('2017-04-26').valueOf()) / (3600 * 24 * 1000);
     dates.str = $('#datetimepicker10').val();
      alert(dates.str);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: so the code didn't work because it was inside document.ready? it finally worked, thanks!